# Equivalent MD5 from CryptoJS and Python Hashlib

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, hashlib

I try to bring some code from JS to Python.
I'm stuck with that code in JS :

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

var txtToHash = "Hello¤World¤";
var md5sum = crypto.createHash('md5');
md5sum.update(new Buffer(txtToHash, 'binary'));
md5val = md5sum.digest('hex');
// equivalent to
// crypto.createHash('md5').update(urlPart, 'binary').digest('hex'));
```

Returns : 
`3a091f847ee21c7c1927c19e0f29a28b`

And, in Python 3.7 I have this code :

```
import hashlib

txtToHash = "Hello¤World¤"
md5val = hashlib.md5(txtToHash.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Returns : `f0aef2e2e25ddf71473aa148b191dd70`

Why are they different please ? I can't find an answer on Google or SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using two different character encodings during digest creation.

Make sure that you have the same type of character encoding. your node js implementation is using 'binary' alias 'latin1' encoding. Where as the code in python uses UTf8 character encoding.

When you specified txtToHash.encode() , this means that encode the text to utf-8.

So modify your digest creation to match the character encoding the same on both the environments.

either modify your nodejs code

```
md5sum.update(new Buffer(txtToHash, 'utf8'));
```

or modify your python code to

```
md5val = hashlib.md5(txtToHash.encode('latin1')).hexdigest()
```

the above should give the same result >> 3a091f847ee21c7c1927c19e0f29a28b

Note:
Although the python code gives the desired result. I wouldn't suggest this because latin1 encoding has only a small subset of characters compared to utf8. So I recommend that you change the encoding to utf-8 in your node js app and apply the same encoding in python too

Comment: I can't change the JS code. I have to transpose it to Python. I don't understand why `txtToHash.encode()` is not equivalent to `new Buffer(txtToHash, 'binary')`. How can I transform txtToHash to bytes (binary) ?

Comment: its definitely not the same. what you are doing in python is just applying the character encoding to UTF8. Whereas in node you are creating a buffer without a UTF-8 encoding. so they are having different character encoding when the code comes to the digest creation

Comment: So how can I write it in Python please ?

Comment: That works! Thank you a lot :) But why does it work with latin1 and not with utf-8 ?

Comment: @djawed: You are using 'binary' encoding in your nodejs app. 'binary' is an alias for 'latin1'. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you very much. Hope this will help others.